# How to use includes with more like this sunspot solr rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

How can I use rails includes method with a sunspot slor more like this query

```
Sunspot.more_like_this(xyz)
```

The xyz var is my Design model variable and i want to use **include method** to include associated Designer and Image model

I want to use the includes method outhere the way we use it for a sql query

```
Model.where(:something => something_else).includes(:model2)
```

Comment: you read [api doc](http://sunspot.github.io/docs/Sunspot/Rails/Searchable/ActsAsMethods.html#searchable-instance_method) `Sunspot.index( User.includes(:account).limit(50) );
Sunspot.commit
`

Comment: I don't want to add it as default option nor do want index the associated object